# How does Spring Data MongoDB repository query concatenation work?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When I create a method of a Spring Data repository like `findByName(…)` everything works fine. But when using `findByField1AndName(…)` Spring Data MongoDB generates query only for the last parameter:

```
{ name : 'qwerty' }
```

But I expected it generates

```
{ field1 : 'something', name : 'querty' }
```

What's the problem? Please help.

UPD1:
If anyone has such a problem, you can use @Query annotation to manually build your query, example below:

```
@Query("{ region: ?0, product: ?1, direction: ?2, deliveryCondition: ?3, sortament: ?4}")
QuotationKey findByRegionAndProductAndMarketDirectionAndDeliveryConditionAndSortament(
        Geography region, Product product, MarketDirection direction,
        DeliveryCondition deliveryCondition, Sortament sortament);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if am missing something.
I tried 1.0.3 and 1.0.4 and it still doesn't work. The only working version right now looks like 1.0.1

When i tried for something like findByZipCodeAndName with 1.0.3 and 1.0.4, this is what i see in logs

```
MongoQueryCreator [DEBUG] Created query Query: { "zipCode" : "test"}, Fields: null, Sort: null
```

With 1.0.1 it works as expected:

```
MongoQueryCreator [DEBUG] Created query { "zipCode" : "test" , "name" : "blah"}
```

Apparently in the new releases only the first field is interpreted and queried for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you stumbled over a [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-469) present in 1.0.2 and 1.1.M1. The fixes have been out for a while so upgrading to a recent version (1.0.4, 1.1 RC1) should do the trick.

Comment: I used spring-data-mongodb 1.0.3.RELEASE, it seems that bug still there.

Comment: If you think so, please file a bug with a test case included :).